# PHP Search and edit database

Tags: php, database

I have a search page that searches database. Once search it brings up results to a page that has a form where they can edit the entries. Yet when I try to edit the entry it comes up with "Subject Editing failed." I cannot see what I have done wrong. 
Here is edit.php.

```
 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
 //form was submitted

$First_Name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["First_Name"]);
$Last_Name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["Last_Name"]);


$message = "Your details have been received";

//Database Query
$query  = "UPDATE subjects SET ";
$query .= "First_Name = '{$First_Name}'";
    $query .= "Last_Name = '{$Last_Name}'";

$query .= "LIMIT 1";

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
if($result && mysqli_affected_rows($connect) == 1)
    {
        //Success
        echo "Subject Edited. ";
    }
else
    {
        //failure
        echo "Subject Editing failed. ";
    }
 }
```

And Here is form:

```
 <form action="edit.php" method ="post">

 <p>First_Name
 <?php     
 $fquery = $_GET['fquery'];
 $lquery = $_GET['lquery'];
 $fquery = htmlspecialchars($fquery);
 $lquery = htmlspecialchars($lquery);
 $fquery = mysql_real_escape_string($fquery);
 $lquery = mysql_real_escape_string($lquery);
 $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM member
 WHERE (`First_Name` = '$fquery') AND (`Last_Name` = '$lquery')") or       die(mysql_error());

 if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){
    $string = "";
    while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){                 
            $string .= "<p class=\"name\">".$results['First_Name']."  "; 
         } 
    } 
else{ 
    $string = "No results"; 
} 
echo $string; ?>            
 <input type="text" name="First_Name" value ="" />
 </p> 

 <p>Last Name: 
 <?php     
 $fquery = $_GET['fquery'];
 $lquery = $_GET['lquery'];
 $fquery = htmlspecialchars($fquery);
 $lquery = htmlspecialchars($lquery);
 $fquery = mysql_real_escape_string($fquery);
 $lquery = mysql_real_escape_string($lquery);
 $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM member
 WHERE (`First_Name` = '$fquery') AND (`Last_Name` = '$lquery')") or die(mysql_error());

 if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){
    $string = "";
    while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){                 
            $string .= "<p class=\"name\">".$results['Last_Name']." "; 
         } 
    } 
else{ 
    $string = "No results"; 
} 
echo $string; ?>            
 <input type="text" name="Last_Name" value ="" />
 </p>
```

Once form submitted the database will update query. Thanks for any help!!

Comment: I don't see a question. Have you used basic debugging methods such as `error_reporting(E_ALL);`, `mysqli_error()` and printing the query before execution `print $query; $result = ..`?

Comment: Yes I have @kingkero It didnt give me any errors until I added the code they all sent me. It doesnt give me errors in DreamWeaver but when submitted it spits out an error. Warning: mysqli_affected_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home/content/96/11465396/html/edit.php on line 29
Subject Editing failed.

Answer (score 0):

Your query fails as there is no appropriate seperators on your statement.

See here

```
$query  = "UPDATE subjects SET ";
$query .= "First_Name = '{$First_Name}'"; 
    $query .= ",Last_Name = '{$Last_Name}'"; //<---------- Comma added (before last name)

$query .= " LIMIT 1";//<----- Space added before LIMIT
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you need a comma and additional spaces in your query. Right now you query would look like this:

```
UPDATE subjects SET First_Name = '{$First_Name}'Last_Name = '{$Last_Name}'LIMIT 1
```

When you need it to look like this:

```
UPDATE subjects SET First_Name = '{$First_Name}', Last_Name = '{$Last_Name}' LIMIT 1
```

You should ALWAYS check your query results and log errors.  In this case you would have been specifically told you had a syntax error in your query.

You also might be well-server to not use a bunch of string contatenation to build your query, and perhaps even use parametrized prepared statements.  In that case you could write your SQL like this:

```
$query = <<<EOD
UPDATE subjects
SET First_Name = ?, Last_Name = ?
LIMIT 1
EOD;
```

This is much more readable in code.

Comment: It never gave me an error until after I added your codes. Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home/content/96/11465396/html/edit.php on line 28
Subject Editing failed.   Dont know where to go from here as I did what you guys said and it still produces an error. Hopw do I see what that error means?

Comment: What could I do now? @Mike Brant

Comment: @King It seems that your did not actually create a database connection and assign the value to `$connect`. that is what that error message is telling you.